# Duplicate content inside iframe on other domain - is it bad?

Tags: seo, iframe

My website has reviews pages for cars.

Some other website wants to show the reviews in his website too.

The implementation is an `iframe` on HIS website loading the an URL in my website with the review. Under the `iframe` (not inside it), there is a link to my website for the full page with the reviews.

Is it ok with Google? Are there better implementations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google doesn't crawl the content within an iframe. So if this person has a website, hosting your site within an iframe then there will be no SEO impact.

Ref: https://moz.com/community/q/does-google-index-a-content-in-iframe